# Cannot create a Google Compute VM instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I thought that this would be relatively straight forward, but I cannot start a Google Compute Engine instance at all. I am creating an instance through the web interface, but get an error after clicking the "Create" button.

The error that appears in the activity log is:

> Invalid value for field 'resource.type':
>   'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects//zones/asia-east1-b/diskTypes/pd-standard'.
>   Must be a URL to a valid Compute resource of the correct type.

Here is a screen shot of my instance settings:

[image]

Any ideas about what is going wrong? I have tried different zones and VM sizes.

Comment: I had no trouble creating an instance with the same parameters as in your screenshot, and since you're getting the error for different zones/VM sizes, it may be an issue affecting your specific account. Please use the grey `Send feedback` link in the bottom-right corner to submit this as an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're unable to create the instance, but you can always create it directly from the terminal with gcutil.

This command should do the trick: gcutil addinstance --zone=asia-east1-b --image=debian-7-wheezy-v20140606 --machine_type=g1-small bigquery-bi-instance